# Вывод массива в определенной последовательности.(php)

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив с элементами который выводит подряд все. Как сделать что бы массив сначала выводил элементы со значением 1 а потом 0?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [rsort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rsort.php).

Пример:

```
$digits = array(1, 0, 0, 1);
rsort($digits);
```